# How to begin a text selection in a Visual Studio macro

Tags: visual-studio

Long ago in a former editor, there was the ability to begin a macro, and then "open" the text selection...such that if your next action was to, say, search for some string - the text selection would then extend to that spot.

This was a great way to do fairly sophisticated operations without having to use wildcards or regular expressions.

Is there a similar facility in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Are you recording a macro or writing one by hand?

Comment: Well, ideally I would be recording a macro - but have a way to "open" a text selection prior to doing something that moves the caret (like a search.)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-= is the answer.

It is the 'SelectToLastGoBack' command, officially documented as "Selects from the current location in the editor back to the previous location in the navigation history".  So, get the cursor where you want to begin your selection (preferably using something reliably repeatable like a search), start a new search (usually I like ctrl-I better than ctrl-F because I can see what it's doing, but ctrl-I seems to not work right in macros), have the search end where you want to end it (esc to close search box), and hit control equals to select back to where you started.

Unfortunately I can't really find anything that explains in detail how the editor decides what the previous location in navigation history is.